# How do I assign values to a numpy array(/opencv image) based on the index

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, optimization, computer-vision

I do generative animation, and have been playing around with animating based off a single function. I'm essentially creating a 3 dimensional vector field that takes in x and y values as well as a time, and then returns the red, green, and blue values. Because the x and y values are parameters, I haven't been able to come up with a better way to generate each frame than by assigning each pixel via for loop, which obviously takes an obscenely long time. Is there some faster way to do this with slicing that I'm not aware of? A better package/data structure for me to use? Or is this just a task that will take a ridiculously long time?

I'm currently using this method to generate each frame:

```
def frame(bgr, xpixels, ypixels, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax, t):
    image=np.empty((ypixels, xpixels, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
    for x in range(xpixels):
        for y in range(ypixels):
            image[y][x]=255*bgr((xmax-xmin)*(x/xpixels), (ymax-ymin)*(y/ypixels), t)
    return image
```

where `bgr` is a lambda. It works, but at a pace of about a second of video every 5-10 minutes.

edit: I should have specified the implementation of `bgr` which is

```
bgr = lambda x, y, t : np.array(((np.sin((x+y)*(t/20))+1)/2, (np.sin(x+y+(t/20))+1)/2, (np.sin(x*y*(t/20))+1)/2))
```

but fortunately I was helped anyway.

Comment: What does the `bgr` do? Please provide [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Depending on your implementation of `bgr`, you may not need to use the for loop at all. Or perhaps you could use numba instead.

Comment: Vectorize the bgr lambda using np.frompyfunc and see if it improves the speed

Comment: Whether you can vectorize the loop depends on the definition of `bgr()`. Please provide it (see [mre]). You could also try using [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/).

Comment: Thank you for letting me know, here's bgr:

bgr = lambda x, y, t : np.array(((np.sin((x+y)*(t/20))+1)/2, (np.sin(x+y+(t/20))+1)/2, (np.sin(x*y*(t/20))+1)/2))

Comment: And further thanks to both Ken and Cris for suggesting Numba, which did exactly what I was looking for once I switched bgr from a lambda to a regular fuction, which perhaps I should have done in the first place. Got my runtime down from the order of days to hours.